# How to prevent html page from zoom out after specific height

Tags: html, css

Hi everyone,
            i make an html page,i want to prevent the page from zoom out after certain zooming out.
my html code is below

```
<style type="text/css">
.main-container {
background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
height: 1508px;
width:  1300px;
}
</style>
//main container
<div id='container'>
my contents will be here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Access to the browser's zoom control state is not scriptable (universally).

See: [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)